# How to get the HTTP response from WebVIew in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm trying to sign in to an app via WebView, and at the end of the process it gives me a response with a token. How can I get the response data from the WebView? Any workarounds for this?

[image: The example of the response]

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can launch request url in a webview and inject javascript to get response. Example code using flutter webview plugin:

```dart
final webView = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
webView.launch(requestUrl); //hidden: true if necessary
webView.onStateChanged.listen((event) async {
  if (event.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
    final response = await webView
      .evalJavascript("document.documentElement.innerText");
    print(response);
  }
);
```

Comment: In my case `webView.onStateChanged.listen` not trigger  do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) you can get your response by injecting javascript like that:

```
 late WebViewController _controller;
```

your webview widget

```
 WebView(
         initialUrl: YOUR_URL,
         javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
           _controller = controller;
         },
        onPageFinished: (finish) {
          //reading response on finish
          final response = await _controller.runJavascriptReturningResult("document.documentElement.innerText");
          print(jsonDecode(response)); //don't forget to decode into json
         },
       ),
```

Comment: `WebView` is now legacy and got replaced with `WebViewWidget` that does not implement `onPageFinished`